# Обновить приложение без Google Play

Tags: android, firebase, google-play, apk

**Кратко**: у меня есть приложение apk от одного бренда. Приложение нельзя загрузить в Google Play из-за правил. Клиенты скачивают приложение из сайта или рассылок (просто apk качают)
К приложению подключены Google Analytics, Firebase для взаимодействия с аудиторией.
Есть необходимость обновлять иногда приложение для улучшения качества, для настройки ивентов и тд.

**Вопрос**: как дать пользователям новую версию приложения?

Вижу вариант обновлять apk на сайте. Но это затронет не так много юзеров. Я хочу чтобы все получали обновления, даже те кто на сайт не заходит.

Может есть вариант как то через пуши это делать?
Нужно чтобы юзеру не приходилось лезть на сайт и качать новую версию.

Возможно в Фаербейс есть какие лазейки?

Comment: Если вас не интересуют правила плей маркета, то ваше приложение может качать что угодно откуда угодно и далее все упрется лишь в пермишен "установка из неизвестных источников". Ну и  rustore есть (не у всех конечно)

Comment: @vitidev я бы с удовольствием загрузил его на плей маркет - но оно оттуда вылетит со свистом я полагаю. У меня больше вопрос как пользователям его обновлять. Посредством чего давать игроку новую версию апк.

Comment: Непонятно в чём проблема... Вы хотите обновляться скрытно от пользователя? Если нет - при запуске приложения проверяйте версию с сайта, ФБ или откуда угодно, предлагайте юзеру скачать обновление через диалог, уведомление и т.п., оттуда откройте ему сайт в браузере или сами загрузите файл и запустите в систему на открытие - там юзеру будут предложены дальнейшие действия со всеми предостережениями.

Comment: @woesss не, не скрытно. Просто ищу варианты куда ему впихнуть обновление, как ему показать что есть новая версия. В идеале продумывал вариант давать обновление через пуши. Условно получил пуш о новой версии, кликнул на пуш, оно загрузило новый apk, юзер установил. Но так походу нельзя технически) А мое приложение - это просто вебвью сайта, если быть точнее.

Comment: Да можно и через пуши, но тогда нужно следить за версиями через аналитику, а она работает когда работает приложение - вопрос: зачем посылать письмо через Америку самому себе, если можно сразу на месте сделать то, что вы собираетесь сделать получив это письмо?... Единственный плюс - после выпуска обновления вы напомните о приложении юзеру, который давно им не пользовался, но и это может не сработать из-за ограничений ОС или юзер запретил показ уведомлений

Comment: @woesss именно, сейчас аналитику как раз изучаю. Напомнить про новую версию с помощью пушей это маст хев. А как мне юзера с пуша перекинуть сразу на файл обновления? новый apk будет при этом на сайте, + по ссылке изи скачивается

Comment: только напоминайте раз в неделю и с возможностью отказаться на это время. иначе это очень бесит.

Comment: @peachcat ставите в уведомление Action, в него интент на нужную вам активити с данными, по которым вы в этой активити определите что нужно показать страницу загрузки.

Answer (score 0):

можно. реализовал такое недавно.
бэк присылал сетевой ответ с кодом версии, ее названием и URL на прямое скачивание файла.
использовал библиотеку `Fetch` чтобы скачать файл
https://github.com/tonyofrancis/Fetch
после, когда файл уже скачен, вызываете установщик АПК-файлов:

```
  private fun getApkInstallIntent(apkPathInstall: String): Intent {
        val toInstall: File = File(apkPathInstall)
        return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            val apkUri: Uri =
                getUriForFile(
                    applicationContext,
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                    toInstall
                )
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE)
            intent.data = apkUri
            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION + FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            intent
        } else {
            val apkUri: Uri = Uri.fromFile(toInstall)
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            intent.setDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive")
            intent.flags = FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            intent
        }
    }
```

не забудьте указать `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />` в Манифесте

все это было засунуто в ForegroundService